# After distro upgrade to 17.10; dpkg --configure -a fails for linux-image-4.13.0-16-generic

Tags: upgrade, kernel, dpkg

I got errors while running the graphical update to ubuntu 17.10 from 17.04. Afterwards the system wont boot anymore. I managed to boot into recovery-mode from an old kernel and re-establish wifi following tutorials.

After running the following I get dependency errors:

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

[photo of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCmVi.jpg)

I also tried the following with the same result:

```
apt-get install -f
apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-4.13.0-16-generic
apt-get --fix-broken install
```

Is there anything else I can try? I hope I gave all the relevant information.

Comment: @mikewhatever I dont understand. At leat the release notes say 4.13. Do I missunderstand? Should I install another image instead?

Comment: You are right, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing linux-image-generic instead of linux-signed-image-generic

Is the signed-image UEFI related?

Comment: Yes, the signed-image could be UEFI related. I get a very similar error: https://photos.app.goo.gl/40wvXyzc79eCUeS23

Comment: Maybe try reinstalling or reconfiguring plymouth?

`dpkg-reconfigure plymouth` and btw. the logs should probably somewhere in /var/log (maybe syslog oder kern.log, depends on how far the boot process worked)